# In DB2, are materialized query tables dropped if one of its source tables is dropped?

Tags: db2

For example, I have a table GAME and PRICE, then I have an MQT called FPS_PRICE that is created using the following statement:

```
SELECT A.GAMENAME, B.GAMEPRICE
  FROM GAME A, PRICE B 
  WHERE A.GAMEID=B.GAMEID 
    AND A.GAMETYPE='FPS';
```

If either the table GAME or PRICE gets dropped... does the MQT FPS_PRICE get dropped as well?

(I would test it out for myself, 
but I don't have administrator access for the database in question)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Info Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000945.html):

> All indexes, primary keys, foreign keys, check constraints,
>   **materialized query tables**, and staging tables **referencing the table
>   are dropped**. All views and triggers that reference the table are made
>   inoperative. (This includes both the table referenced in the ON clause
>   of the CREATE TRIGGER statement, and all tables referenced within the
>   triggered SQL statements.) All packages depending on any object
>   dropped or marked inoperative will be invalidated. This includes
>   packages dependent on any supertables above the subtable in the
>   hierarchy. Any reference columns for which the dropped table is
>   defined as the scope of the reference become unscoped.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent an MQT from being dropped? Or at least prvent the DROP (maybe with a warning) that will cause the MQT to be dropped?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Other object types have a `RESTRICT` clause on `DROP`, which prevents it from being dropped if other objects reference it, but `TABLE` does not have that clause.

Comment: You absolutely use `WITH RESTRICT ON DROP` in your MQT's `CREATE TABLE` statement.  If you do this, attempts to drop the table on which the MQT is based on will result in the error `SQL0672N  Operation DROP not allowed on table ...`.

Comment: You can also use `ALTER TABLE x ADD RESTRICT ON DROP` for existing tables and MQTs.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde ah, brain fart. I was only looking at the `DROP` page on Info Center. I'm not sure why I didn't think that it would be a `CREATE` / `ALTER` statement. :-/

Answer (score 0):

The way to prevent it being dropped is to make it with a simple CREATE TABLE, rather than making it a materialized table.

Comment: I assume you can still get data from source tables and refresh this data object in the same way an MQT works?